# Converting Vector Arrays to Numbers

Tags: c++, stdvector

I created a function that converts numbers to arrays in C++. Due to this creation, I also created the opposite which converts arrays back to numbers:

```
int convertToNumber(vector<int> nums) {

    int length{ nums.size() };
    int Pow{ length - 1 };
    int factor{ pow(10, Pow) };
    int tempNum{};
    int result_num{};

    for (auto n : nums) {

        tempNum = n;
        tempNum *= factor;
        result_num += tempNum;
        Pow--;

    }

    return result_num;
}
```

Here is the issue. When I run this using the following code in main:

```
int main() {

  vector<int> nums {2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 6};

  int number = convertToNumber(nums);

  cout << number << endl;

}
```

I get 2,400,000 when I should be getting 235,626. I searched for a long time could not find the logic error within the code. Does somebody know what's going on?

Comment: note, with `int convertToNumber(vector<int> nums)` you are making a copy of the vector, which is not so efficient. Instead pass by const reference `int convertToNumber(vector<int> const& nums)`. And also note that `int` is quite big for a sinlge digit. `uint8_t` might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With every iteration of your loop, you are updating `Pow` - but not `factor`; and it is `factor` that's used in your loop, not `Pow`.

Remember that when you assign an expression to a variable, that expression is only evaluated *once*, and the result of this single evaluation is what the variable is set to. In other words, the `pow()` function is not called each time you use `factor`; it's only called once with the initial value of `Pow`.

Note the code you provided would not compile. You must specify the namespace before identifiers such as `vector` and `pow` - they will not be understood by the compiler otherwise; and you will also need to include the appropriate headers.

If, by chance, you had a `using namespace std` hiding somewhere in your program - well, don't use that:

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1593077)

Comment: I am always making stupid mistakes in my program so I am thankful that you pointed that out. Also, I did use `#include <vector>` and `#include <windows.h>`. `<windows.h>` has a math header nested somewhere in it so I didn't have to explicitly include `<math.h>` or `<cmath>`. I also used `using namespace std` but I didn't know that was bad practice. I will view the link you posted.

Comment: @HyperTextMarkupMan: I assumed you had those headers somewhere... But when asking on StackOverflow, your code examples should be such that we can simply copy-paste and compile, and not have to do extra work to fill in the missing bits. This is expected both as a courtesy and as a means to ensure you haven't introduced any "copy-and-paste errors" (something which happens a lot). Obviously you get more leeway since you're new :-)

Comment: Ok! Noted. I will try in the future to do that! It would probably make it so much easier on you guys!

Answer (score 2):

KIS (keep it simple)

```cs
int convertToNumber(std::vector<int> const& nums) {
    int result_num{0};
    for (auto n : nums) {
        result_num *= 10;
        result_num += n;
    }
    return result_num;
}
```

or even use an algorithm

```cpp
int convertToNumber(std::vector<int> const& nums) {
    return std::accumulate(cbegin(nums), cend(nums), 0,
        [](int a, int n) { return a*10+n; });
}
```

Comment: I always tend to make things more complicated than I should. This is a good reminder that I should always think simple. Thank you.